# How to get Current running app if my current app is in background android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As getRunningTasks(1) is deprecated what can I use as a alternative of this

Answer (score -1):

Please consider the following option

```
val tasks = context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE).
appTasks
for (task in tasks) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stackId: " + task.taskInfo.stackId)
        }
```